# Error converting image with Spipu\Html2Pdf

Tags: laravel-5, html2pdf

In my laravel 5.7 / Blade app I use Spipu\Html2Pdf and tring to convert some html code which contains image ref I got error :

```
Spipu \ Html2Pdf \ Exception \ ImageException (2)
Unable to get the size of the image [/storage/user-avatars/-user-avatar-5/rad_soang_avatar.jpg?dt=1545812433]
```

Searching in net I found that in some other systems(not laravel) I have to made some wrapper for any image, but I did not find
which kind of wrapper it must be for laravel/blade app?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to wrap image url with asset method, like :

```
<img src="{{ asset($image_url]) }}
```

?